# .htaccess produce 404 page not found in IE

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, typo3

I'm working on Typo3 version 4.7.4. When I can access the Front End of the site in every browser excepts IE (in all version). After replacing the customized .htaccess file to the default .htaccess of the Typo3 version 4.7.4, it works fine. Then I compared both files I couldn't find something different except some more configurations. However, I'm not sure if those new configurations has killed IE. Here is my new .htaccess configuration:

```
#####################################
###     Compression via TYPO3     ###
#####################################
<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/css" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gzip

##################################################
###     Browser caching of resource files     ###
##################################################
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>

########################################
###     Settings for mod_rewrite     ###
########################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

### Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
#RewriteBase /

### IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ - [F]
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ - [F]

#RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

############################################################################
###     Redirect all users directly to the https version of the page     ###
############################################################################

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#############################
###     Miscellaneous     ###
#############################
Options -Indexes

########################################################
###     Disable *.ts files viewing from Frontend     ###
########################################################
<FilesMatch "\.(ts)$">
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please check your code: "Redirect all users directly to the https version of the page" there is no redirect. "RewriteRule .* index.php [L]" is defined twice.

Comment: That's a point. I comment out the above line and it works. However I get another issue. It breaks my PIE.htc behavior. Thanks maholtz for help.

Comment: please update your code here. And comment out the "RewriteCond" too, you have always some RewriteCond  follwed by an RewriteRule. Check difference between pie.htc and PIE.htc if the url to PIE.htc is correct.

Comment: Hmm, I found it. I copy it to the css/ directory and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks maholtz for help.

```
#####################################
###     Compression via TYPO3     ###
#####################################
<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/css" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gzip

##################################################
###     Browser caching of resource files     ###
##################################################
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>

########################################
###     Settings for mod_rewrite     ###
########################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

### Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
#RewriteBase /

### IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ - [F]
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ - [F]

#RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

############################################################################
###     Redirect all users directly to the https version of the page     ###
############################################################################

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#############################
###     Miscellaneous     ###
#############################
Options -Indexes

########################################################
###     Disable *.ts files viewing from Frontend     ###
########################################################
<FilesMatch "\.(ts)$">
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that the bug is here `# RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`